# Cannot resolve method 'requestLocationUpdates

Tags: android, android-studio, gps

I recently started with Android Development and I want the app to show longitude and latitude values. However, the getLastKnowLocation() always return null, so I tried to use requestLocationUpdate() but there is an error. Here are my code:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)    getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();


public final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location!=null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

           lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,2000,10,locationListener);
    }

};
```

Here are my imports:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
```

And my uses-permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
public final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong `LocationListener`. You need to import [android.location.LocationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html)

Comment: hi, thank you very much for answering. but now, `new LocationListener()` got this error: _Class 'Anonymous class derived from LocationListener' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onStatusChanged(String, int, Bundle)' in 'LocationListener'_

Comment: Well sure, the two LocationListeners are completely separate classes and have different methods you need to provide.

Comment: please take a look at my updated code. am I doing this correctly? there is an error for `this` saying that it is the _Wrong 1st argument type_

Comment: Your permission check code is within your `onLocationChanged()` callback (and so is your `requestLocationUpdates()` call). Those should both be outside that in a method in your Activity (note you can't call `requestLocationUpdates()` unless the permission is granted - your current code calls it anyways even if not granted).